# What is source of the Saraswati sloka " Saraswati namastubhyam varade kamarupini..."?

Tags: shloka, saraswati

Saraswati Sloka is a Hindu prayer chanted before beginning a class or at the beginning of one’s studies, so that all learning may resolve in knowledge alone. It is addressed to the **Goddess Saraswatī**, who symbolizes all forms of knowledge, including the knowledge of the performing arts. Knowledge is a fundamental pursuit of human life, and a life of study and learning provides nourishment and discipline to the human intellect. In the Vedic culture, study is considered as one’s duty. (**Wiki source**)

Saraswati Sloka:

> सरस्वति नमस्तुभ्यं वरदे कामरूपिणि ।
>
> विद्यारम्भं करिष्यामि सिद्धिर्भवतु मे सदा ॥

What is origin for this Sloka? and in Which scripture is it found? Also who composed the sloka?

Answer (score 7):

Not sure which scriptures contain it or if it is at all part of any scripture or not or simply an independent work.

Anyways, it is part of [a famous Saraswati stotram composed by sage Agastya](http://greenmesg.org/mantras_slokas/devi_saraswati-ya_kundendu.php).

The 5th verse of the stotram is the verse you have quoted:

> सरस्वति नमस्तुभ्यं वरदे कामरूपिणि ।
>  विद्यारम्भं करिष्यामि सिद्धिर्भवतु
> मे सदा ॥५॥
>
> Sarasvati Namastubhyam Varade Kaama-Ruupinni |
>  Vidya[a-A]arambham
> Karissyaami Siddhir-Bhavatu Me Sadaa ||5||
>
> Meaning:
>
> 5.1: Salutations to Devi Saraswati, Who is the Giver of Boons and Fulfiller of Wishes,
> 5.2: O Devi, When I Begin my Studies, Please Bestow on me the capacity of Right Understanding, always.

And, the concluding verse of the stotram mentions the author as Agastya Muni:

> इत्थं सरस्वतीस्तोत्रम् **अगस्त्यमुनिवाचकम्** ।
>  सर्वसिद्धिकरं नॄणां
> सर्वपापप्रणाशणम् ॥२१॥
>
> Ittham Sarasvatii-Stotram **Agastya-Muni-Vaacakam** |
>  Sarva-Siddhi-Karam
> Nrrnnaam Sarva-Paapa-Prannaashannam ||21||
>
> Meaning:
>
> 21.1: Thus this Saraswati Stotram **composed by Sage Agastya**, ...
> 21.2: ...Leads to all Accomplishments and Destroys all Sins.

BTW, there are few such stotrams which were composed by Mahamunis but may be independently. That is, they may not be linked to a particular scripture.

One such example is [Shiva Daridra Dahana Stotram](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Daridrya_Dahana_Shiva_Stotram).

As stated:

> **Vasishtena Krutham** stotram, Sarva sampathkaram param,

It is also composed by Vashishta Muni but may be independently.