# What is the origin of this Saraswati prayer found in various Stotras & Stutis?

Tags: scripture, identification-request, goddess, shloka, saraswati

I have recited this prayer to Goddess Saraswati since childhood:

> yA kundendu tushhArahAradhavalA yA shubhravastrAvR^itA 
>   yA vINAvaradaNDamaNDitakarA yA shvetapadmAsanA
>   yA brahmAchyutasha.nkaraprabhR^itibhirdevaiH sadA vanditA 
>   sA mA.n pAtu sarasvatI bhagavatI niHsheshhajADyApahA

I am not sure which scripture it comes from can anyone help?

EDIT - people trying to mark the question as a duplicate kindly note the so called Agastya Stotra that is the answer in the other question is NOT the only source of this verse. No point linking this to that since this particular prayer is found in multiple texts including the Bhavabhuti Subhashita.

Comment: See this Q: This may or may not be part of any scripture. Anyways we know who composed it. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20043/what-is-source-of-the-saraswati-sloka-saraswati-namastubhyam-varade-kamarupini

Comment: @Rickross the link you shared is for a different verse.

Comment: NO, the very first verse of Agastya Krita Saraswati Stotram is the verse you're asking about. There OP picked up yet another verse from the same Stotram. Read the stotram here: http://greenmesg.org/stotras/saraswati/saraswati_stotram.php

Comment: Oh okay. So where does this Stotram come from?

Comment: It may not be from any scriptures like i said in that answer there. It's famous as the Agastya Krutha Saraswati Stotram.

Comment: Hmm well am looking for the source so it would be great of someone can find the original scripture it belongs to.

Comment: As i have said it may not have any scriptural source at all. Some Stotrams are like that. For eg see the Daridra Dahana Shiva Stotra by Sage Vashishta. It is also probably not part of any scripture, but still it is as authoritative. http://www.hindudevotionalblog.com/2013/01/daridraya-dahana-shiva-stotram-lyrics.html

Comment: Ya but that doesn't help since it is still a might not a conclusive yes or no.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is source of the Saraswati sloka " Saraswati namastubhyam varade kamarupini..."?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20043/what-is-source-of-the-saraswati-sloka-saraswati-namastubhyam-varade-kamarupini)

Comment: First, the verse is NOT a part of the so called Agastya Stotra as shared in the comments section of Keshav's answer in fact it can be found at multiple places. Second, it is quite a sweeping statement to say that a verse is not found in any scripture at all! No one could have gone through ALL the extant scriptures to make that claim ever. The best someone can say is that he or she hasn't come across the verse anywhere yet :)

Answer (score 2):

This is the first verse of the famous [Saraswati Stotram](http://greenmesg.org/stotras/saraswati/saraswati_stotram.php):

> yā kundendutuṣārahāradhavalā yā śubhravastrāvṛtā 
>   yā vīṇāvaradaṇḍamaṇḍitakarā yā śvetapadmāsanā । 
>   yā brahmācyutaśaṃkaraprabhṛtibhirdevaiḥ sadā pūjitā 
>   sā māṃ pātu sarasvati bhagavatī niḥśeṣajāḍyāpahā ॥
>
> (Salutations to Devi Saraswati) Who is Pure White like Jasmine, with the Coolness of Moon, Brightness of Snow and Shine like the Garland of Pearls; and Who is Covered with Pure White Garments, Whose Hands are Adorned with Veena (a stringed musical instrument) and the Boon-Giving Staff; And Who is Seated on Pure White Lotus, Who is Always Adored by Lord Brahma, Lord Acyuta (Lord Vishnu), Lord Shankara and Other Devas, O Goddess Saraswati, Please Protect me and Remove my Ignorance completely.

The last verse of the hymn says it was composed by Agastya:

> itthaṃ sarasvatīstotram agastyamunivācakam । 
>   sarvasiddhikaraṃ nṝṇāṃ sarvapāpapraṇāśaṇam ॥
>
> Thus this Saraswati Stotram composed by Sage Agastya Leads to all Accomplishments and Destroys all Sins.

But as far as I know it's not found in any scriptures.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71763/discussion-on-answer-by-keshav-srinivasan-which-scripture-contains-this-prayer-t).

Comment: Btw, I've found that one [shrIsarasvatIdhyAnam](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/sarasvatIdhyAnam.html?lang=sa) also contain that mantra.

Comment: I think the verse is available in different places I just read it in the Subhashita by Bhavabhuti - http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_z_misc_subhaashita/yavarga1.htm therefore finding the original source makes even more sense now.

Comment: I doubt that this was by Agastya, feels very modern and more of a Kalidasa timeframe / style.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in following answer:
[What is source of the Saraswati sloka “ Saraswati namastubhyam varade kamarupini…”?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20043/1049)

The verse is **not found** in any scripture.

Comment: Why do we need a comunity wiki answer even after there is a non wiki answer saying the same? Moreover, Saraswati Namastubhyam and Yakundendu Tusharahara are two different verses. This answer doesn't serve any purpose.

Comment: Two different verses but of the same Stotra...Do we need to have 10 Qs for 10 such verses of a same Stotra?  "This answer doesn't serve any purpose." The other answer also does not serve any purpose either after my answer there. @Sarvabhouma At least this better as it is has intentionally been made a wiki. The intention is good.

Comment: First, the verse is NOT a part of the so called Agastya Stotra as shared in the comments section of Keshav's answer in fact it can be found at multiple places. Second, it is quite a sweeping statement to say that a verse is not found in any scripture at all! No one could have gone through ALL the extant scriptures to make that claim ever. The best someone can say is that he or she hasn't come across the verse anywhere yet :)

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal, actually this answer is posted as part of [this meta discussion](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1106/1049), which relates to your this Qn. This is a wiki-answer, if you feel that the wordings are not proper, then feel free to edit it. It's open for all.

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal Cool down. I am not at all against ur question. We are just discussing how "ethical" it is to answer such exactly similar Qs without adding anything from our own side. As u can see, the non-wiki answer hardly adds anything to the discussion.after my comments and the answer there. So, it's about the answer given and not about ur Q at all.

Comment: Second, it is quite a sweeping statement to say that a verse is not found in any scripture at all! **No one could have gone through ALL the extant scriptures to make that claim ever** --  That's exactly why i am against the answer given by Keshava. With that one line (that it is not found in any scriptures) he is answering the Q. It should be deleted. @Dr.VineetAggarwal

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal See [this](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1106/how-is-this-even-an-answer-that-my-flag-was-rejected#comment4565_1106) comment of mine. I am saying exactly the same thing as you are. So, i am against the answer given by keshav and not ur Q.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but your comment on my question was also to the same effect. I dont think anyone can claim that ever :)

Comment: Yes but that was just a comment (not an answer). I have said "it may or may not be part of any scriptures ( I can at the most say that we don't know)". But i can not answer saying just that "AFAIK it's not part of a scripture" That can not be accepted as an answer.The answer should be deleted that's my point. @Dr.VineetAggarwal You can support my Meta post.